Error while executing Batch script in yaml pipeline
I keep getting this error while trying to setup build for installer project which generates msi. I followed steps mentioned here Setup Build pipeline for Visual Studio Installer Project

Task 'Batch script' is using legacy execution handler 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.ProcessHandlerData' which is not supported in container execution flow

Yaml looks like this:
variables: # More settings at https://aka.ms/obpipelines/yaml/jobs
  devCmd: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com'
  disableToolPath: 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild'

- task: BatchScript@1
  displayName: Enable .vdproj Builds
  inputs:
      filename: '"$(disableToolPath)\DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe"'
      workingFolder: '"$(disableToolPath)"'


There is the same question here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-batchscript/781426

The BatchScript task is using an older handler in the agent, and it’s
not compatible with Windows containers. Fortunately, you can switch it
out for the CmdLine task, which is fully supported.

Try to use CmdTask: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/cmd-line-v2?view=azure-pipelines
something like that:
- script: "$(disableToolPath)\DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe"
  workingDirectory: $(disableToolPath)


Are you using a MS-hosted agent or a self-hosted agent? If you are using a self-hosted agent, is it a VM or Windows container or something else? If it's a Windows container, try to use CmdTask as suggested by Shamrai Aleksander. According to this official doc,

BatchScript@1 task is not compatible with Windows containers. If you need to run a batch script on a Windows container, use the command line task instead

I have followed the blog shared by you and used MS-hosted agent windows-2022 to build my Visual Studio Installer Project. The pipeline runs successfully when using BatchScript@1 task to enable .vdproj Builds.


I am using a windows container image, which doesn't have the visual studio installer project installed. So i am struggling with multiple issues here right now.

Do you know how to install the Visual Studio Installer project inside the windows container image on the pipeline like how we install dotnetcore and nuget etc.

Hi @Ashutosh Kumar, you can check whether this ticket is helpful for you.  The cause of your original issue is that BatchScript@1 task is not compatible with Windows containers and the solution is using command line task. If the ticket shared doesn't work for you, create a new question about how to install Visual Studio Installer project extension inside your  container. Or you can use MS-hosted agent windows-2022 to build your project.
